# How to use external css to target: blank;

Tags: html, css, target

For some reason

```
a {
  target: _blank;
}
```

doesn't work in external css, is it possible, or will I have to do internal for all my links?

Comment: `target` isn't a CSS attribute, it's an HTML attribute on an anchor (`a`) element.

Comment: we don't have any property in css like `target:blank`.You have to add this in `a` tag only